# How to use facebook login in my app

Tags: node.js, facebook

### api/ users.js

```js
var fb = {
    clientID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:4268/auth/facebook/callback'
};

var fbCallback = function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(accessToken, refreshToken, profile);
};

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(fb, fbCallback));
    

router.get('/', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope:"email"}));
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',function(req, res) {
    res.send("logged in");
});
```

I have put this code in the folder `api` with the name `users.js` and when I do facebook login I am using `localhost:4268/api/user/`. After login, I am expecting the message "logged in" but it is not. Is there any mistake in callback url ??